# Combining two complex SQL queries

Tags: mysql, select, join

So I've arrived at the absolute limit of my sql prowess and I can't for the life of me combine these two queries,  First off here's what my database looks like

Current - Table

```
ID - Unique identifier for device (Int)  
Location -Unique identifier for name of area (VarChar)  
Status - The current status of the device (VarChar )  
Time - DateTime of when the last connection was made to the device (DateTime)
```

Historical

```
CID (Sorta unused, just as an AI field to store multiple old bits of data uniquely) (Int)  
ID - Unique identifier for device (Int)  
Location --Unique identifier for name of area (VarChar)  
Status - The current status of the device (VarChar )  
Time -- DateTime of when the last connection was made to the device (DateTime)
```

So with that all said here's the two queries:

Query 1:

```
SELECT *, if(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), TIME)) >=1, 1, 0) as OlderThanAnHour
FROM Current
WHERE Location like "MyLocation"
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT ID, min(time), (abs(timestampdiff(HOUR,NOW(),TIME))/count(*)*100) as percentage
from Historical
where LOCATION like "MyLocation"
group by ID
```

My goal is to combine them into a single query, since it's going to be called often

Comment: What do you mean by combine?

Comment: At the moment, `Percentage` will essentially be a random value since it's a function on `TIME`, not an aggregated function of `TIME` - should it be using `min(TIME)`?

Comment: Nope, it should be using the min(TIME) as selected from before...

Comment: So you want to return a random value in `percentage`?

Comment: @boisvert -- I mean use a join statement to turn query1 and query2 into a single query

Comment: @MarkBannister is right, I updated my previous answer, in the meantime change `TIME` to `min(TIME)`

Comment: @MarkBannister it returns the same data for me with or without min() before the time.

Comment: Do the ID fields in Current and Historical reference the same device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       if(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), c.TIME)) >=1, 1, 0) as LatestOlderThanAnHour,
       min(h.time) as EarliestTime, 
       (abs(timestampdiff(HOUR,NOW(),min(TIME)))/count(*)*100) as percentage
FROM Current c
JOIN Historical h on c.ID = h.ID
WHERE c.Location like "MyLocation"
group by c.ID
```

Comment: That is some really good work right there, I want to let you know that I really appreciate the help on this.